# How to retrieve bounding boxes from rendered latex that may contain math expressions?

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I'm wondering if there is a path to retrieve bounding boxes of the rendered glyphs (text, math symbols, etc) from latex. `pdftotext` supports partially of that but won't cover non-text glyphs like `\frac{}{}`. Ideally, there should be association produced for the glyphs and their corresponding bounding boxes.